# When I try to update the order, it changes the total amout to 0

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have added new custom order status to Woo Commerce by using following function.

**Register New Order Statuses**

```
function wpex_wc_register_post_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipping-progress', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Shipping In Progress', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Approved (%s)', 'Approved (%s)', 'text_domain' )
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wpex_wc_register_post_statuses' );
```

**Add New Order Statuses to WooCommerce**

```
function wpex_wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-shipping-progress'] = _x( 'Shipping In Progress', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wpex_wc_add_order_statuses' );
```

whenever I go to edit order and changed the order status to newly added custom order status and click on Save Order button, and go back to Orders it shows Total "0"...

- **Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?**

Comment: you need to update amount as well..

Comment: Would you mind telling me how exactly I can do that?

FYI: If I update my order status to Woo commerce default status, amount don't get set to 0, but only if I try to update order status to one of my custom statuses...

Comment: Can anyone help here please...???